# Dropdown with database searching dynamic dependence

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax

Currently, I was trying to make multiple chain dropdown lists.

The data was json format something like.

```
 [{"y":1,"x":1,"name":"5M","value":0},
 {"y":1,"x":2,"name":"5L","value":2},
 {"y":1,"x":3,"name":"5K","value":16},
 {"y":1,"x":4,"name":"5J","value":0},
 {"y":1,"x":5,"name":"5H","value":0},
 {"y":1,"x":6,"name":"5G","value":1},
 {"y":1,"x":7,"name":"5F","value":8},
```

The dropdown idealized was like the footer filter of this example from datatable.

http://live.datatables.net/gejojiqu/1/edit

All of the dropdown select lists can be dynamic dependent after one or many attributes (column) were selected.

For example like when I select the 1st dropdown list which belongs to the "name" attribute with "Bradley Greer", the "position" dropdown select value will only remain "Software Engineer" and so on the other dropdown select value.

[image: example]

Any idea or guidance that how can I achieve this dropdown?
I search for a lot of related guidance about cascading dropdowns non of their data format was similar to mine.

Any help was appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find the solution by myself by using jQuery and struggling for a night:

```js
const my data = [
{
    "Data": "aaa",
    "Media": "1",
    "Row": "1",
    "Column": "3",
    "Code": "24",
},
{
    "Data": "aaa",
    "Media": "2",
    "Row": "1",
    "Column": "1",
    "Code": "24",
},
{
    "Data": "aba",
    "Media": "3",
    "Row": "1",
    "Column": "3",
    "Code": "24",
},
{
    "Data": "aab",
    "Media": "4",
    "Row": "1",
    "Column": "2",
    "Code": "24",
},
{
    "Data": "aab",
    "Media": "1",
    "Row": "2",
    "Column": "1",
    "Code": "24",
},
{
    "Data": "aab123",
    "Media": "1",
    "Row": "2",
    "Column": "1",
    "Code": "23",
},
]


mydata.forEach(function(row,index) {
   mydata[index] = Object.values(mydata[index]);
});





function makeDropDown(data,filtersAsArray,targetElement){

    const filteredArray  = filterArray(data, filtersAsArray);
        const uniqueList = getUniqueValues(filteredArray,filtersAsArray.length);
    populateDropDown(targetElement,uniqueList);

}



function applyDropDown(){
        const selectLevel1Value = document.getElementById("level1").value;
    const selectLevel2 =  document.getElementById("level2");
        makeDropDown(mydata, [selectLevel1Value], selectLevel2);
    applyDropDown2();
    applyDropDown3();
    applyDropDown4();
}

function applyDropDown2(){
        const selectLevel1Value = document.getElementById("level1").value;
    const selectLevel2Value = document.getElementById("level2").value;
    const selectLevel3 =  document.getElementById("level3");
        makeDropDown(mydata, [selectLevel1Value, selectLevel2Value], selectLevel3);
}



function applyDropDown3(){
        const selectLevel1Value = document.getElementById("level1").value;
    const selectLevel2Value = document.getElementById("level2").value;
    const selectLevel3Value = document.getElementById("level3").value;
    const selectLevel4 =  document.getElementById("level4");
        makeDropDown(mydata, [selectLevel1Value, selectLevel2Value, selectLevel3Value], selectLevel4);
}


function applyDropDown4(){
        const selectLevel1Value = document.getElementById("level1").value;
    const selectLevel2Value = document.getElementById("level2").value;
    const selectLevel3Value = document.getElementById("level3").value;
    const selectLevel4Value = document.getElementById("level4").value;
    const selectLevel5 =  document.getElementById("level5");
        makeDropDown(mydata, [selectLevel1Value, selectLevel2Value, selectLevel3Value, selectLevel4Value], selectLevel5);
}


function afterDocumentLoads(){
        populateFirstLevelDropDown();
        applyDropDown();
}


function getUniqueValues(data,index){
      const uniqueOptions = new Set();
    data.forEach(r => uniqueOptions.add(r[index]));
    return [...uniqueOptions];
}


function populateFirstLevelDropDown(){
        const uniqueList = getUniqueValues(mydata,0);
    const el = document.getElementById("level1");
    populateDropDown(el,uniqueList);
}

function populateDropDown(el,listasArray){
      el.innerHTML = "";
    
    listasArray.forEach(item => {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.textContent = item;
        el.appendChild(option);
    });

}

function filterArray(data, filtersAsArray){
   
   return data.filter(r => filtersAsArray.every((item,i) => item === r[i]));
}



document.getElementById("level1").addEventListener("change",applyDropDown);
document.getElementById("level2").addEventListener("change",applyDropDown2);
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", afterDocumentLoads);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>


<label>Data</label>
<select class="js-example-basic-single" id="level1" name="level1"></select>
<label>Media</label>
<select class="js-example-basic-single" id="level2" name="level2"></select>
<label>Row</label>
<select class="js-example-basic-single" id="level3" name="level3"></select>
<label>Column</label>
<select class="js-example-basic-single" id="level4" name="level4"></select>
<label>Code</label>
<select class="js-example-basic-single" id="level5" name="level5"></select>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dontooleng/ycadmofk/157/)